# Check if a variable with a name from a config file is set

Tags: php

In a PHP function, I need to check if a variable is set. However the variable name is, well, variable. It can be changed from within a `config.php` file. Looks like this:

```
//config.php
class config {
  const array = 'name';
}
```

So I need to check if a variable with the name `config::array` (in this case `$name`) exists. This is what I've come up with:

```
$array = config::array;
if(isset($$array)) return true;
```

Notice the two dollar signs. Since `$array == 'name'`, `$$array` becomes `$name` - at least in theory. I've tested this and it seems to be working as intended. However, I'm not sure if it's actually doing what I want - is it? If yes, is this a good way of doing this or is there a better one? If not, how do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
$array = config::array; 
if (isset($$array))
{
   $array = $$array
};
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not accurate enough. I'm not trying to check if the const `array` exists within the config class. `config::array` defines the name of a variable that can live somewhere in the code. So if `config::array` returns `'name'`, I wanna check if somewhere in the code, the variable `$name` is set. If `config::array` return `'randomstring'`, I wanna check if somewhere in the code, the variable `$randomstring` is set.

Comment: probably could return isset($$array); to simplify it

Comment: I need to run additional checks on the array. Will something like this also work? `$array = config::array;
  $array = $$array;
return(isset($array));`

Comment: You'll get a PHP notice when you try to reference $$array if there isn't a name variable

Comment: So better to do $array = config::array;
return isset($$array);

Comment: Ok and if I turn it around, i.e. `$array = config::array; if (isset($$array)){$array = $$array};` so that I can use `$array` in the rest of the function?

Comment: yea that would work since you'll know that there is a variable with that name to reference

Comment: Thank you! Maybe edit all of that in your answer for future reference :)